# What's the simplest way to update these form fields with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html form:

```
<form>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apples" /><input type="text" value="false" /><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="oranges" /><input type="text" value="false" /><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="grapes" /><input type="text" value="false" /><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="bananas" /><input type="text" value="false" /><br/>
</form>
```

Now I want to write some javascript/JQuery such that when I check or uncheck a checkbox, the corresponding text box shows "true" or "false". It should be easy to add more fruits without changing the javascript.

What's the best way to do this in an elegant way?

Comment: You really need to show something like an attempt.  Right now It is more like an order for some help. Instead what did you google, what did youtry why do you not thing your way is elegant.  I have clients using exactally your language, "it should be easy to..." We are not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

this is easy in pure javascript, you don't really need jQuery. Just assign onchange event of each checkbox with a function that would update the textfield, there has to be a relation between the checkbox and textfield. The function could be something like:

```
// assign to onchange like: onchange="updateTextField(this)"
function updateTextField(cb) {
  // this assumes that the corresponding text field has id with the same name as the
  // checkbox value
  var tf = document.getElementById(cb.value);
  tf.value = cb.checked.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some sort of relationship between the checkbox and the text field.  Something like this would work using jQuery, and is extremely extendable.

```
<form>
     <input type="checkbox" value="apples" /><input type="text" value="false" for="apples"/><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" value="oranges" /><input type="text" value="false" for="oranges" /><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" value="grapes" /><input type="text" value="false" for="grapes" /><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" value="bananas" /><input type="text" value="false" for="bananas"/><br/>
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $('input[for$="' + $(this).val() + '"]').val("true");
        } else {
            $('input[for$="' + $(this).val() + '"]').val("false");
        }
    })
})
</script>
```